# DPDK mbuf deep copy

Tags: deep-copy, dpdk

I'm pretty new to DPDK.

I have a packet that I need to duplicate several times 
meaning I want to deep copy `mbuf`
the only mbuf api command I've found :

```
static struct rte_mbuf* rte_pktmbuf_clone(struct rte_mbuf *md,struct rte_mempool *mp )
```

does not seems to `deep-copy` it by just pointing to the same data payload.
my question is how can I properly `deep copy` `mbuf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging , I didn't find any simple API.
this is what I came up with : 
going over all mbuf segments and copying it to new mbuf

**please note** this code won't work directly , you need to implement `get_data_from_mbuf` and `mbuf_free`

```
 rte_mbuf *myJumboMbuf = m_pPoolMgr->getJPktPool()->getMBuf();
 for (rte_mbuf *m = (rte_mbuf*)mbuf; m != NULL; m = mbuf_api_next(m))
 {
     uint16_t u16DataLen = mbuf_api_get_data_len(m);
     char* buffer = rte_pktmbuf_append(myJmboMbuf, u16DataLen);
     if (!buffer)
     {
         mbuf_free(myJmboMbuf);
         ret = ERR_NO_MEM;
     }
     rte_memcpy(buffer, get_data_from_mbuf(m, void*), u16DataLen);
 }
```